# How may I avoid these plot defects at low CPU cost?

Tags: plotting

I'm disappointed to find may defects in the output of SphericalPlot3D with default quality settings. e.g.

```
SphericalPlot3D[1,{u,0,\[Pi]},{v,0,2\[Pi]},ColorFunction-> 
Function[{x,y,z,u,v,r},ColorData["GreenBrownTerrain"][0.5 +Cos[5 u]]], 
ColorFunctionScaling->False, Lighting->White,Boxed->False,Mesh->False,Axes->False]
```

gives

[image]

and even increasing PlotPoints to 20 only slightly reduces them:

[image]

and in particular *fails to eliminate the marked discontinuity at v==0 which should not be there in the first place*.

Is there any solution less costly than upping PlotPoints further?

EDIT: Somin's comment's suggestion that the cause is SphericalPlot3D messing up the normals seems disproved by the fact the defects appear under ambient-only lighting too:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example where raising the settings of `PlotPoints` or `MaxRecursion` becomes costly? If you don't give the plotting routines much points to work with, of course they will not be able to yield a decent result.

Comment: `SphericalPlot3D[1,{u,0,Pi},{v,0,2 Pi},ColorFunction-> 
Function[{x,y,z,u,v,r},ColorData["GreenBrownTerrain"][0.5 +Cos[5 u]]], 
MaxRecursion->10,PlotPoints->100,ColorFunctionScaling->False, 
Lighting->White,Boxed->False,Mesh->False,Axes->False]` looks good

Comment: @JM, See the example I already gave. "If you don't give the plotting routines much points to work with, of course they will not be able to yield a decent result" Firstly, this call uses the default, not any number I have given. Secondly, I expect a lower nnumber of points to give lower resolution, not the defects pictured.

Comment: @Young, that's a good example of costly. >12x CPU time measured here.

Comment: The discontinuity thing came up recently, SphericalPlot3D messes up the vertex normals. Try ParametricPlot3D instead.

Comment: @Simon, Thanks. But ParametricPlot3D seems a lot more costly. Recoding to use that exceeds the memory limit here (free plan), even with PlotPoints->5. Any lower gives a silent fail - no output.

Comment: @Simon, "messes up the vertex normals" seems not to be the cause, since the defects show under ambient lighting too.

Comment: That's not what Simon meant. The vertex normals of the surface are computed independent of what sort of lights are used. As you've noticed, the unsightly seam is there even if you have changed the lighting settings. That is why Simon was telling you to try `ParametricPlot3D[]`.

Comment: "The vertex normals of the surface are computed independent of what sort of lights are used." Indeed, but the the vertex normals' expression is highly dependent of the kind of lighting. And that expression should be nil under ambient e.g. directionless lighting. If you can tell me how else messed-up vertex normals can cause these defects, please go ahead.